# I created several stored procedures in phpmyadmin, how to call them using an sql query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I created several stored procedures in phpmyadmin, how is it possible to call them using an sql query (mysql) ?

Answer (score 4):

```
CALL name_of_stored_procedure(parameters);
```

Try this on the 'SQL' tab:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storedprocedure1`(OUT myvar1 CHAR(64))
SET myvar1="IT ";
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storedprocedure2`(OUT myvar2 CHAR(64))
SET myvar2="WORKS";
```

Then call:

```
CALL procedure1(@var1);
CALL procedure2(@var2);
SELECT @var1,@var2;
```

Answer (score 4):

the above example does work except for typo - should be:

```
CALL storedprocedure1(@var1);
CALL storedprocedure2(@var2);
SELECT @var1,@var2;
```

just missed the "stored" prefix of the procedure name off the the CALL's

Answer (score -4):

As far as I know phpmyadmin doesn't support this.

Comment: You can create/edit/execute stored procedures from phpmyadmin. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19197966/179669)