# Creating functions in phpMyAdmin - Error: access denied you need the super privilege for this operation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I imported a MySQL database. All the tables where successfully imported but not the functions. The only way I can execute SQL queries is through phpMyAdmin or with a PHP script (no SSH).

Here's an example of the functions to import:

```
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `f_calc_gst` */;;
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=""*/;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER=`journal`@`%`*/ /*!50003 FUNCTION `f_calc_gst`(p_ht decimal(15,3), p_province varchar(2)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
begin
  declare res varchar(255); 
  declare v_gst decimal(15,3);
  declare v_gst_formula varchar(255);

  select GST, GST_formula
  into v_gst, v_gst_formula
  from taxes_periods
  where NOW() between dt_debut and dt_fin
  and id_province = p_province;

  set v_gst_formula = replace(v_gst_formula, 'HT$', p_ht);
  set v_gst_formula = replace(v_gst_formula, 'GST%', v_gst);

  set res = concat('select round(', v_gst_formula, ',2) "gst"');
  return res;
end */;;
```

If I paste this code in phpMyAdmin I get this error: *#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation*

I tried removing the "/*!50003" and the "*/" to uncomment the SQL but I get the same error message.

I also tried not using any delimitors and removing "DELIMITER ;;" and got this error:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_calc_gst SET SESSION SQL_MODE =  "" CREATE DEFINER =  `journal`@`%` FUNCTION  `f_calc_gst` (

p_ht DECIMAL( 15, 3 ) ,
p_province VARCHAR( 2 )
) RETURNS VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARSET utf8 BEGIN declare res VARCHAR( 255 ) ;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET SESSION SQL_MODE=""
CREATE DEFINER=`journal`@`%` FUNCTION `f_calc_gst`(p_ht ' at line 2
```

Also tried :

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`journal`@`%` FUNCTION `f_calc_gst`(p_ht decimal(15,3), p_province varchar(2)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
begin
  declare res varchar(255); 
  declare v_gst decimal(15,3);
  declare v_gst_formula varchar(255);

  select GST, GST_formula
  into v_gst, v_gst_formula
  from taxes_periods
  where NOW() between dt_debut and dt_fin
  and id_province = p_province;

  set v_gst_formula = replace(v_gst_formula, 'HT$', p_ht);
  set v_gst_formula = replace(v_gst_formula, 'GST%', v_gst);

  set res = concat('select round(', v_gst_formula, ',2) "gst"');
  return res;
end//
```

resulting in :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Is the problem in the SQL, phpMyAdmin or with the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store procedures in phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080681/store-procedures-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't using the delimiter field before looking at this post. I tried it but I still have the same error:
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was I didn't have the super privilege but if I remove the DEFINER from the query I don't need this privilege anymore.

> As of MySQL 5.0.3, CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION require the
>   CREATE ROUTINE privilege. They might also require the SUPER privilege,
>   depending on the DEFINER value, as described later in this section. If
>   binary logging is enabled, CREATE FUNCTION might require the SUPER
>   privilege, as described in Section 18.6, “Binary Logging of Stored
>   Programs”.

Also had to set the delimiter field under the SQL text box.
[image: phpMyAdmin Delimiter field]

Here's the SQL Query without the DEFINER statement:

```
/*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `f_calc_gst` */;;
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=""*/;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50003 FUNCTION `f_calc_gst`(p_ht decimal(15,3), p_province varchar(2)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
begin
  declare res varchar(255); 
  declare v_gst decimal(15,3);
  declare v_gst_formula varchar(255);

  select GST, GST_formula
  into v_gst, v_gst_formula
  from taxes_periods
  where NOW() between dt_debut and dt_fin
  and id_province = p_province;

  set v_gst_formula = replace(v_gst_formula, 'HT$', p_ht);
  set v_gst_formula = replace(v_gst_formula, 'GST%', v_gst);

  set res = concat('select round(', v_gst_formula, ',2) "gst"');
  return res;
end */;;
```