# mysql: DELIMITER syntax error at line 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to add this function using the following SQL in phpmyadmin/MySQL

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `__myv`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE   FUNCTION `__myv`(`a` int, `b` int) RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN

    return FLOOR(a / b);
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

but I get this error:

Error

```
SQL query:

DELIMITER;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
```

How to fix this error??

Comment: Need space between DELIMITER and the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if DELIMITER is a console command, phpMyAdmin's import module has accepted it since many years. When opening a database and clicking on SQL, a query entered there is passed to the import module, so it should work (unless you have a very old phpMyAdmin version).

Answer (score 6):

DELIMITER is a Mysql console command, You can't use it in phpmyadmin. 
To set the delimiter in phpmyadmin, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802061/1385896)

Comment: in the mysql console? or in phpmyadmin?