# phpmyadmin sql event getting error when trying to declare variable

Tags: sql, variables, phpmyadmin, declare

I'm new to sql so bear with me, but I'm trying to create an event that will populate the row of a table at a specific time with values from 1 to x where x is a pre-declared variable.  I'm attempting to use a delimiter for the first time and I'm not really sure where all my semi-colons should be at but the following is what I assumed after a while of reading:

```
DELIMITER $$
    DECLARE day_m INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET day_m = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%e');

    WHILE day_m <= DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), '%e')
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO monthly_scheduling (days) values (day_m)
            SET day_m = day_m + 1
        END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The error I'm getting is as follows: `MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ DECLARE day_m INT DEFAULT 0; SET day_m = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, ' at line 1`

I've been trying all sorts of things but I can't get the event to create because of the error I seem to keep getting at the `DECLARE` section.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need an @ symbol when setting your variable? Also your WHILE line has the variable as "days_m" instead of "day_m", not sure if that is a typo in your code or copy paste.

Comment: From what I understand you only need the @symbol for session specific variables rather than local variables.  Actually the @ symbol was how I was first declaring the variables until I read further into it.  Thanks for pointing out the typo, I removed it from the code but I still get the error at the same position in the code: right at the DECLARE statement.

Comment: The error is including your $$ delimiter as part of the syntax. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313481/mysql-delimiter-syntax-error-at-line-1

Comment: Yea I've removed the delimiter from the syntax but I still get an error at the same spot.  I checked that thread but it seems that it directs you to setting a delimiter in the "Run SQL Query/Queries" section of phpmyadmin, whereas I'm trying to create an event and that delimiter option isn't available within the event creation.

Comment: Which MySQL and phpMyAdmin versions are you using?