# PhpMyAdmin - err 1064 - set variable in function

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting hard time with PhpMyAdmin.
My table is :

```
material(id_item, id_collection,...)
primarey_key(id_item, id_collection).
```

I want to make a function to prevent loop in Acyclic Graph Database. So i want to force id_collection > id_item for new id_collection.

My function is (i have set `//` in SQL tab):

```
    //

CREATE or REPLACE function collections_prevent_cycle()
 BEGIN
    DECLARE max_of_both SMALLINT;
    SET max_of_both := (MAX(GREATEST(id_item, id_collection)) FROM material);

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT id_collection FROM material where id_collection = NEW.id_collection) THEN
        IF (NEW.id_item >= max_of_both) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You may not insert items that doesnt exist';

        ELSEIF(NEW.id_collection <> max_of_both + 1) THEN SIGNAL'45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You may not insert non stable id_collection';
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN 0;
 END;

//
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'function collections_prevent_cycle() RETURN integer BEGIN
>   DECLARE max_of_b' at line 1

I'm messing with declare but can't get rid off - Anyone could help me plz?

Fixed my first pbm of Delimiter with :

- [Delimiter in PhpMyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801550/creating-functions-in-phpmyadmin-error-access-denied-you-need-the-super-privi/16802061#16802061)

Comment: Installed Adminer - Seems to be both DELIMITER & declare pbm :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to the error.

First :

> - It seems u can't use NEW & OLD keywords in function on MYSQL. So i made a Trigger instead.
> - Switched to Adminer instead of PHPmyAdmin to use DELIMITER I notice  DELIMITER*(space)$$* means *(space)$$* and not only *$$*
> - SET := didn't work so I use basic SELECT ... INTO... FROM
> - CREATE or Replace doesn't existe - u have to separate operations.

Here is the code i made which compile but doens't work.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS collections_prevent_cycle $$
CREATE trigger collections_prevent_cycle 
BEFORE insert ON material FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE max_of_id_item SMALLINT;
    DECLARE max_of_both SMALLINT;

    SELECT MAX(GREATEST(id_item, id_collection))     
    INTO max_of_both    
    FROM material;

    SELECT MAX(id_item)
    INTO max_of_id_item
    FROM material;

    IF ((SELECT id_collection 
          FROM material 
          WHERE id_collection = NEW.id_collection) = NULL) THEN
            IF (NEW.id_item > max_of_id_item) THEN             
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You may not insert items that doesnt exist';

            ELSEIF (NEW.id_collection <> max_of_both + 1) THEN             
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'            
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You may not insert non stable id_collection';
            END IF;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

My Goal was to force insertion this way :

- If a new collection id is added - It must be the (Max id of both collection & item) + 1
- If a new collection id is added - It must contains an existing item (id_item < max(id_item))

If anyone have an idea why trigger doesn't trigger - I'm out of gas :'(.

EDIT : 
I tested both sub imbricated IF (IF & ELSEIF) They work alone.

**THEREFORE it is the FIRST IF which fail.**

I suppose = NULL is not adequate BUT can't find the answer in the documentation of the possible outcomes for a query.

I Dig this way - If anyone have a beautiful solution I take it . Kappa.

EDIT 2 : It Works!

```
(SELECT count(*) 
          FROM material 
          WHERE id_collection = NEW.id_collection) = 0)
```

Replaced 
By

```
(SELECT count(*) 
          FROM material 
          WHERE id_collection = NEW.id_collection) = 0)
```

So the query returns 0 when it's empty (instead of this obvious empty ressources).

I won!