# Mysql event error using php

Tags: php, mysql, events, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to initiate a MySQL Event using a PHP script. It works using phpMyAdmin (although I get the same error) but not using the script. I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE EVENT myevent21222
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
DO
  BEGIN
    UPDATE `team` SET `reg` = '0' WHERE `id` = '1';
  END |
  # MySQL lieferte ein leeres Resultat zurück (d.h. null Datensätze).
DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone figure out the problem?

Is there any alternative for changing data in a database after 5 minutes after a user had done something?

Comment: How does the error message end?

Comment: Don't add the delimiter part to your code. phpMyadmin does that for you automatically

Comment: Oh, now it should work, I think. But I get the following message: "Errormessage: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet". Well, I'll try it using mysqli_query ...

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: You have 3 questions, none have accepted check marks, and no upvotes on those that help you?

Answer (score 3):

**Create the Event:**

```
drop event if exists `myevent21222`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE EVENT myevent21222
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  BEGIN
    UPDATE `team` SET `reg` = '0' WHERE `id` = '1';
  END |
  # MySQL lieferte ein leeres Resultat zurück (d.h. null Datensätze).
DELIMITER ;
```

**Turn on the event handler:**

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;  -- turn her on and confirm below
```

**Confirm it is on:**

```
show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';
```

**Check out event info:**

```
show events from so_gibberish2; -- note so_gibberish2 is my database name
```

-- obviously use your database name above

[image]

Look at the manual page for what [ON COMPLETION PRESERVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) means as well as other things.

Disable or enable it:

```
ALTER EVENT myevent21222 disable;
ALTER EVENT myevent21222 enable;
```

Comment: Already works by deleting the Delimiter part. Nevertheless, thank you very much!

Comment: glad you got it working. Don't forget it is still running :p

Answer (score -1):

you must set the *DELIMITER** first:

see for phpmyadmin 
: [Creating functions in phpMyAdmin - Error: access denied you need the super privilege for this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801550/creating-functions-in-phpmyadmin-error-access-denied-you-need-the-super-privi/16802061#16802061)

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT myevent21222
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
DO
  BEGIN
    UPDATE `team` SET `reg` = '0' WHERE `id` = '1';
  END |
  # MySQL lieferte ein leeres Resultat zurück (d.h. null Datensätze).
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: The first Post i have seen]

Comment: i have not seen **DELIMITER |** before in the question, and it works then

Comment: But not in phpMyAdmin

Comment: and OP has change his question

Comment: Actually not, he only added the rest of the error message

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801550/creating-functions-in-phpmyadmin-error-access-denied-you-need-the-super-privi/16802061#16802061

Comment: @juergen d - i dont know why you downvote. i have add a screenshot from the 1 post i have seen and there was no ** DELIMITER** set

Answer (score -1):

Try  this.

```
     DELIMITER |

     CREATE EVENT myevent21222
     ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
     DO
        BEGIN
        UPDATE `team` SET `reg` = '0' WHERE `id` = '1';
        END ;
       # MySQL lieferte ein leeres Resultat zurück (d.h. null Datensätze).
     DELIMITER |
```