# Code running every 24hours that updates data in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to ask how can I do something like this.
I want every 24 hours to update the value in the table in the database
and I don´t know how it can be done.

I need to it to be automatic, that means I won't be doing anything it will just do it on itself when its time

I am using MySQL database with
PHP version is 7.0

So how it can be done? 
I don't need code (but I don't mind) but the mechanism, I want just description can I put some code into the database and it will do it automatically or run some file on server or?

Comment: What operating system. Linux systems can use cron jobs, Windows can use scheduled tasks

Comment: Depending on the database, it may support scheduled jobs.  such as http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html for mysql

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Comment: Thanks all for help, I think I will use mysql events.

Comment: Just change your interval accordingly [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37901661)