# Execute MySQL event in two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL event, works fine so that's not my problem, the problem here is I want to execute that event `on month n/5th/year n and on month n/19th/year n`
for example `on 10/4/2016 and then on 10/19/2016` it is possible to combine both dates in one event? If not what could be a solution?

I'm thinking in this option:

1- Create 2 events, every month, one on day 5th the other on 19th.

Sorry for not post code but this is not a code question.

Comment: your question is a bit confusing. You could create an event with an if statement wrapping the block with a check on `curdate()`

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better, but your opinion could be a solution I understand just I don't have much clear if I use and if statement what should be my time interval to execute the event?

Comment: idk. Maybe you want it to start the check everyday at noon. If so, with [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37901661/1816093) it would be `12:00:00` instead of `00:00:00` . Make sure you honor the `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`.

Comment: That's the moment when my question comes, I don't want to execute the event everyday, I want to know if is possible to execute this event for example on October 4th and then on October 19th, as you can see I think that an option could be creating 2 different events, 1 for day 4th and the other for day 19th

Comment: The event is sitting there scheduled by a thread seen in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. It fires once a day, only once a day, hits the `IF` and bails out. Total time like minuscule. You are way too over micro optimizing this in thought and wasting billions of joules of energy on it versus just one event that has no impact on system performance. Then in a month you manually delete the event. Note, it is the Scheduler that has the thread mainly, sleeping. The event does not until fired.

Comment: In other words, Much to Do about Nothing. Focus on bigger issues :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use **crontab** to execute events for your possible date/time. **Crontab** accept 5 parameters to set execution date/time.

```
* * * * *  YOUR_COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE
```

Here every * is a single parameter for **Contab**.

```
* --> min (0 - 59)
* --> hour (0 - 23)
* --> day of month (1 - 31)
* --> month (1 - 12)
* --> day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is also Sunday)
```

**Example**

```
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
```

Here is details about the **crontab** [Overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview)

Comment: MySQL built-in their event framework (high overview snippets [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935/1816093) ) for the exact purpose of eliminating `cron`

Comment: That said, in all fairness, in many hosting environments only cron is available (cannot be abused, say, not more than 1 can fire in a 15 minute time period, else your acct gets frozen). And Events are completely turned off so as to limit any one hoster consuming the server

Comment: Thank you for advance @Drew