# How to drop MySQL tables automatically by date

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have tables named `20161006_cost` and `20161006_area`. The tables' name prefix is from the date they were created.

Can they be deleted automatically with a trigger, if the system date is more than 24 hours from the tables date creation?
Or maybe with SQL or PHP code.

database `mysql`
engine `innodb`

===========================

edited

found the query tho show the table name

```
$qdrop=mysqli_query($connect,"select TABLE_NAME,create_time
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' 
 and CREATE_TIME <='2016-10-07' and TABLE_NAME LIKE '2016%'
");
```

but i can't use fetch array to show it

```
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($qdrop)){
   echo $data['TABLE_NAME'];
}
```

error code:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in E:\xampp\htdocs\....
```

Comment: create an event. Run queries against info_schema. Drop at will.

Comment: 1 minute read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37901661), more in depth [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935) . You need to look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and bank on good table naming conventions. The whole thing is risky. Additionally you would typically need a [Cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html)

Comment: Set a cron which will check the time & will drop the table

Comment: got it. so first show the date creation schema then drop the table with looping.

Comment: Get all the tables name like *_cost, then explode the table name "_". If prefix time < current date then drop the table. Check your mysql user must have table 'drop' privilege.

Comment: Why not just have the tables with a timestamp in it? This would be better than creating tables etc. with the prefix

Comment: @EdHeal becaus mine is not for multi user table. each user has their own table so i have to give the prefix