# Create table on Database based on Joins on other database (same server)

Tags: mysql, sql

can we use the join operation to create a table on a Database (called DB1 in the example) based on two tables from Database another database (called DB2 in the example) ? If yes, then how to do ?

Both databases are on the same server and DBMS is the same. ID1 and ID2 based on table1 in DB2; ID1 and Name based on table2 in DB2

Here´s what I tried out already (but it´s not working)Made from point of view that I´m using DB1:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (ID1,ID2,Name)
SELECT ID1,ID2, DB2.table2
FROM DB2.table1;
LEFT JOIN DB2.table2
    ON ID1=ID1;
```

Thanks for your help again!

Comment: I get an error:  "Code Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't2.value' in 'field list'" - what does that mean? (My column "Name" in the example is originally called value)

Comment: You need to remember that the semi-colon ends the statement. So you orphan the remainder and your aliases are not complete (tables not brought in)

Comment: So it is the equiv of a multi-query but the first one bombs (1054). the fragment after it would be jibberish but it never gets there.

Comment: deleted the semicolon and now get the result I wanted: Big thanks (again) :) !

Comment: Another Question: can I automatically update the data in table 3 coming from table 1 and 2 (let´s say every 24 hours)?

Comment: Sure. [One](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37901661/1816093) and [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935/1816093)

Comment: I rolled back your question. No [Chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478) . Sure I gave you a comment above to help. But don't change the base question. It invalidates the peoples' answers below. Now let's stick a fork in this question. It is over.

Comment: Sorry- I haven´t known that: thanks for your help again :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use proper aliases in your query:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (ID1, ID2, Name)
SELECT t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t2.Name
FROM DB2.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN DB2.table2 t2
    ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
```

Comment: Do we need semicolon,i am not sure about mysql

Comment: @TheGameiswar Good question and I'm not sure myself.  I seem to recall semicolon not being necessary in Workbench, at least not all the time.

Comment: I ditched the semi-colon. Not sure what that was there for (other than the op code)

Comment: @Drew thanks...they should create a duplicate sheriff badge. And you'd get it :-)

Comment: deleted the semicolon - and got the solution! :) Big thanks!

Comment: please mark correct if it solved your problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can create table at the same time insert records:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t2.Name
FROM DB2.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN DB2.table2 t2
    ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
```