# Stored procedure mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Please help me to solve the mistake done in this stored procedure:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `repos`(IN `order_condition` VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8, IN `from_date` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, IN `to_date` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, IN `dept_id` TINYINT(4), IN `type` VARCHAR(15) CHARSET utf8, IN `search_value` VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8, IN `institutionid` INT(11))
    NO SQL
BEGIN

set @strWhere   = "";
set @strWhere   = CONCAT(@strWhere,"t1.inst_id = ",instid);
set @selectstr  = '';
set @selectstr2 = '';
set @joinstr    = '';
set @joinstr2   = '';
set @group2= '';

set @selectstr = CONCAT(",t2.`std_name`");
set @selectstr2= CONCAT(",t5.`student_name`,t5.`roll_no`,t5.`student_id`");
set @joinstr = CONCAT("left join standard_master as t2 on t1.`std_id`= t2.`std_id` ");
set @joinstr2 = CONCAT("left join student_det as t5 on t1.`std_id`= t5.`std_id` ");
set @strWhere = CONCAT(@strWhere," AND t1.std_id = ",dept_id);
set @group2= CONCAT("t5.`student_id`");


SET @query = CONCAT("select t1.* ",@selectstr," , t3.term_name, SUM(t4.amount) as fee_amount",@selectstr2," FROM inst_fee AS t1 ",@joinstr," left join term_master as t3 on t1.term_id = t3.term_id left join inst_amtdet as t4 on t4.masterid = t1.masterid ",@joinstr2,"  WHERE ",@strWhere,  " AND ",@group2,  " NOT IN (select id from student_master) Group by t1.f_name  ", order_condition);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

#select @query;


END
```

It shows a syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN(

Please help me to fix the error. Thanks

Comment: Your code does not have any `IN(`...

Comment: There is IN in parameters.

Comment: @Devart Yes, but it doesn't have a closing parenthesis. When MySQL reports syntax error it always includes a literal quote of the offending code so this is either not the real message or it's triggered by different code.

Comment: @Álvaro González Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct. It works on new MySQL servers.

It is possible that you use old MySQL server, where CHARSET clause was not supported for string parameters. Check the syntax for your server version.

Comment: Thanks.Ya i have used the delimiter when i try to save i am getting the error.cant able to save

Comment: I have changed answer. Check it. What is the server version?

Comment: Ya checcked Its 5.6.21

Comment: Ya I tried but on saving getting error as ,MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ Pls help me to find the solution.

Comment: What client do you use?

Comment: I use Phpmyadmin to access database

Comment: DELIMITER is a client command. As I know, it is not possible to use this comamnd in phpmyadmin. There is an option (workaround) for phpmyadmin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801550/creating-functions-in-phpmyadmin-error-access-denied-you-need-the-super-privi/16802061#16802061

Comment: Or, if it is possible to access the server from your host, you can use mysql command line client, or our free tool dbForge Studio (Express) to run such scripts.

Comment: Ya i have already tried the link given above still i dont get any rectification

Comment: It seems that problem with procedure execution, not creating. Possible - problem with constructed query inside the procedure.

Comment: Also, unknown value `order_condition`.