use if statement in Trigger to add a value with filtering
issue in the Trigger ... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$
create trigger add_not_before_insert before insert on `customer...' at line 1
Hi, I am trying to insert a value in the column Note inside the table customer_payments using if statement inside the trigger, For customer who has previous payment ... Enter the word 'monthly installments' in the column Note ; but if it is the first time for this customer! Enter the word 'first time' in the Note's column
all the tables and the trigger attached to the :
https://dbfiddle.uk/fc-4QQRF

A lot of typos.

customer_payments.note is defined as NOT NULL - hence you cannot insert NULL value explicitly.
DELIMITER is a client command, not SQL statement, it shouldn't be used in the fiddle.
Each separate stmt in the compound stmt, including ones in the IF stmt branch, must be terminated with a delimiter.

fixed fiddle

thanks for your remarks, but the same error appeared

@Abd What client/tool/code do you use? Where does your code is execited in?

i am using phpmyadmin in local host with 10.4.32-MariaDB

@Abd For PMA you'd use the delimiter reassigning method which is specific for this software - see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802061/10138734
