# Error with MySQL syntax in event sql-script. Delimeter already used

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-scripts, mysql-event

I have this script for update table monthly:

```sql
DELIMITER |
CREATE
    EVENT `kpiparams_scheduled_update`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 MONTH
            STARTS '2020-02-01 02:59:59'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    COMMENT 'KPIParams was updated by event_kpiparams_scheduled_update'
    DO
    BEGIN
        UPDATE kpiparams INNER JOIN kpiparams_update
            ON kpiparams.param_name = kpiparams_update.param_name
        SET kpiparams.good        = kpiparams_update.good,
            kpiparams.bad         = kpiparams_update.bad,
            kpiparams.weight_gold = kpiparams_update.weight_gold,
            kpiparams.weight_tech = kpiparams_update.weight_tech,
            kpiparams.is_for_calc = kpiparams_update.is_for_calc
        WHERE kpiparams.param_name = kpiparams_update.param_name;
    END |
DELIMITER ;
```

This code drop exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER | CREATE EVENT kpiparams_scheduled_update ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH ST' at line 1

And this:

> nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER | CREATE EVENT `kpiparams_scheduled_update` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH ' at line 1

I serched some resources that said, I need use Delimeter, don't write amount of months in '' and use BEGIN-END. By the way, it didn't help me.

```java
spring.datasource.schema=classpath*:mysql-scripts/event_update_kpiparams.sql
```

**EDITED SCRIPT:**

```sql
CREATE
    EVENT kpiparams_scheduled_update 
        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2020-02-01 02:59:59'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    COMMENT 'KPIParams was updated by event_kpiparams_scheduled_update'
    DO
    BEGIN
        UPDATE kpiparams INNER JOIN kpiparams_update
            ON kpiparams.param_name = kpiparams_update.param_name
        SET kpiparams.good        = kpiparams_update.good,
            kpiparams.bad         = kpiparams_update.bad,
            kpiparams.weight_gold = kpiparams_update.weight_gold,
            kpiparams.weight_tech = kpiparams_update.weight_tech,
            kpiparams.is_for_calc = kpiparams_update.is_for_calc
        WHERE kpiparams.param_name = kpiparams_update.param_name;
    END
```

Comment: is the hash sign (# 04:00:00 ...) recognized as a comment sign by mysql?

Comment: @Ronald, removed, but it didn't help.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Shouldn't it be easy to remove parts here and there until something works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you tried to run this using JDBC?

You don't need `DELIMITER |` at all. That's a [mysql client builtin command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html). Client builtins are not recognized by the SQL parser.

You can just execute the `CREATE EVENT` statement as a single statement and then you don't need to have a delimiter at the end of the statement. Delimiters are only important in interfaces that support multiple statements (e.g. the mysql client).

---

Okay it seems you are using multiple statements in an `.sql` file and you need some way of separating the statements. Normally this is `;` but you have some statements that contain `;` as part of the statement, not as the separator.

I'm not a Spring developer, but I found [Spring Boot Database initialization MySQLException for Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674803/spring-boot-database-initialization-mysqlexception-for-trigger) which describes the use of:

```
spring.datasource.separator
```

This is also documented: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

> spring.datasource.separator
>
> (default) `;`
>
> Statement separator in SQL initialization scripts.

Comment: The above was paraphrased from an answer I posted in 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19772738/20860

Comment: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: I can't infer how you're calling this. But I tested your CREATE EVENT in the mysql client and I got no error.

Comment: Generally when you get a syntax error complaining about `''` it means the parser reached the end of your SQL statement and expected more. Like a close-parenthesis, or a final `END` or something like that.

Comment: I added line to Answer how I call this sql-script. I can't understand what exactly it expected...

Comment: @Mykola why not simply open a MySQL shell and run the `CREATE` query?

Comment: @NicoHaase, bcs I need to do it here, when it will be on server I wouldn't be able to "run the query"...

Comment: So you defined a statement separator in your Spring configuration, _AND_ you used that separator in your .sql file? I am just guessing at this point, because I don't use Spring. But I guess you must use the statement separator consistently.