# MySQL Create function returns error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, sql-function

I am trying to create a function that returns rowcount. But it returns error  again and again.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION func1(userid INT)
RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_name INT;
  SET var_name = 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_name
    FROM wps_bal
    WHERE u_id = userid;
  RETURN var_name;
END$$
```

Comment: Works for me. How do you execute it

Comment: I have executed in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Strange. Do you have code before that function when you execute? Remove it if so and execute this code only.

Comment: No. There is no more code/command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [This was helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080681/store-procedures-in-phpmyadmin)

I have created the solution:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION func1(userid INT)
RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_name INT;
  SET var_name = 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_name
    FROM wps_bal
    WHERE u_id = userid;
  RETURN var_name;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, you can accept your own Answer after 48 hours.  This will have the effect of removing your Question from the list of unanswered Questions.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your version of PHPMyAdmin does not support the `DELIMITER` statement which is not MySQL statement. Here you can find how to create the function in PHPMyAdmin: [Store procedures in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080681/store-procedures-in-phpmyadmin)