# mysql_free_result() in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, procedure

I want to call a procedure twice in the phpmyadmin, so I must to free the result by calling `mysql_free_result()`, otherwise i'll get an error of number #2014, I tried `mysql_free_result()` but it said there is no function exist, i tried `free_result()` samething, I googled for it and didn't find anything. 
so is it possible to free the result from phpmyadmin ?

Comment: It is not possible to run PHP code from PHPMyAdmin. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490537/i-created-several-stored-procedures-in-phpmyadmin-how-to-call-them-using-an-sql